# Define copyable class with parameterized constructor

Tags: c++, class, copy, default-constructor

I've got a struct which looks like this:

```
struct MatchItem
    {
        const std::string a,b;
        const bool matches = true;
        const bool is_regex = false;

        MatchItem(std::string a):MatchItem("",std::move(a)){}
        MatchItem(std::string a,bool is_regex):MatchItem("", std::move(a),is_regex) {}
        MatchItem(std::string b, std::string a,bool is_regex=false):exchange(std::move(b)), pair(std::move(a)),is_regex(is_regex) {  }
        MatchItem() = default;
        MatchItem(const MatchItem&) = default;
        MatchItem(MatchItem&&) = default;
        MatchItem& operator=(const MatchItem&) = default;
        ~MatchItem() = default;
    };
```

Later in code, I'm calling following function:

```
void my_function(std::initializer_list<MatchItem> items)
{
    items.insert(this->items.end(), mg.items.begin(), mg.items.end());
}
```

This fails to compile with following message:

```
MatchItem &MatchItem::operator =(const MatchItem &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

I did define the `MatchItem& operator=(const MatchItem&) = default;` in the class, but it didn't seem to have changed anything.

Why isn't my class copyable and how do I fix this?

Comment: "_Why isn't my class copyable and how do I fix this?_" It **is** copyable. Nothing you show suggests that it isn't. It isn't assignable, though, due to presence as `const std::string` as a member, since you can't assign to `const` variables.

Comment: `items.insert(this->items.end(), mg.items.begin(), mg.items.end());` won't compile not due to usage of a deleted function but because [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) doesn't have a member function `insert`. Also there looks like some missing member variables that prevents it from being compiled in `struct MatchItem`. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You have stumbled upon one of the reasons why `const` member variables are rarely worth the trouble.

Comment: @Frank yes, that was it. Removing the const fixed it. Strange that you can initiate const members in constructor but cannot copy the class afterwards

Comment: Note that your choice of signatures violates [F.51 of the C++ core guidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-default-args): the first and second constructors should be combined to `MatchItem(std::string a,bool is_regex = false):MatchItem("", std::move(a),is_regex) {}`

Comment: @ArsenZahray Why? That would be like saying "It's strange that I can do `const int x = 3`, but not reassign it afterwards."

Comment: @Frank totally true

Comment: @ArsenZahray "_Strange that you can initiate const members in constructor but cannot copy the class afterwards_" As I already mentioned: you can copy the class just fine. You can't assign to it. There is fundamental difference between copying (which is done only during initialization), and assignment - which can be done multiple times. `const` does exactly that - prevent reassignment. If you don't want to prevent that - don't make the variable `const`.